# Power BI - how to load from a source based on min/max values of another already-loaded source

Tags: powerbi

I am attempting to build a data model in Power BI from a data mart (star schema) in SQL Server.  This data mart has a fact table and several dimension tables.  One of the dimension tables is a date table.  I want to load all rows from the fact table.  However, I only want to load a subset of the date table.  In particular, I want those dates (rows) between the min and max dates in my fact table.  This way, when I create slicers and such, I don't have unnecessary dates appearing.

In other BI tools (e.g., Qlik Sense), the usual solution is to first load the fact table into memory, compute and load its min/max dates into another table (also in-memory), set variables from this other table, load the date dimension table (into memory) based on the min/max variables, and finally drop the temporary table from memory so that it doesn't stay in the model and cause problems.  This seems like the most efficient solution to me.  It only reads the required (as opposed to unnecessary) data from the source dimension table, it doesn't need to perform any joins in the source, and it only reads each table once (as opposed to 2+ times).

How can I achieve this in Power BI?  Or, more importantly, is this solution method even possible in Power BI?

I found [this](https://medium.com/@Konstantinos_Ioannou/powerquery-dynamic-date-dimension-table-filtering-f9201cf87d8a) solution, but it seems inefficient, as it creates 2 queries (instead of just 1) for the min/max and, moreover, it performs the dimension table filtering *after* all rows have already been fetched from the source.  (In my particular case, this isn't too bad.  But, it could be problematic in other situations in which my dimension table is large.)

Comment: It turns out that the solution I referenced does use query folding.  So, the only issue now is how to collapse the 2 queries for the min/max down into 1, and how to remove the resulting table from the model.

Comment: I learned how to remove the resulting tables from my model.  Within 'Transform Data', right-click the desired table in the Queries list, and uncheck 'Enable load'.